# Parse pipe delimited CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

There's a file that I am given that is always in the following format:

[image]

Typically the column names are pipedelimited in cell A1.  Then the value for each column are in columns A and B and they are also pipe delimited.

I've been reading opening these in excel and then using a combination of "Text to columns" and CONCATENATE to format but was wondering whether it'd be possible to process them in python.

For clarity, the desired output is for First Name/Last NAme/Phone/State to each have their own column and to have the values formatted to those columns given the pipe delimiters.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but if it is "Can this be processed in Python?", then the answer is yes, it can.

Comment: So my question is how would I got about processing a file in the format above where the columns are pipe delimited and the rows have some combination or comma and pipe delimitors.

Comment: So basically the screenshot I shared how would I go about getting each vlaue into it's own cell.

Comment: I think it should be possible with just excel by concatenating column B to column A with a pipe inbetween. Then all relevant data is in column A. You could paste this in a new sheet with | as delimiter to spread across multiple columns.

Comment: I mean that's what I'm currently doing, but my goal would be to do this programmatically.

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate is exactly what you are asking, but at least it should give you a nudge in the right direction. If your question is "how can I read files which are _solely_ separated by pipes" that's simpler, and seems to correspond to your prose description; but if it is "how can I split on either (commas or) tabs and pipes, that's also quite common and not very hard. If you need more help, ideally, provide an _exact_ sample of your textual input, and an _exact_ [mre] of code which does most of what you want, but which you can't finish without help.